# $a^z$ is either a constant or unbounded function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to show that

$a^z$ is , where $a$ is a complex number, either a constant or unbounded function, depending on the branch of its logarithm.

I think it is easy to convince that $a^z$ could be unbounded. But I'm not sure that how it could be constant.

Please give me any hint or advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $a=1$, it could be constant.

Comment: Use the fact that $|a^{z}|=e^{x\log|a|-y\theta}$ where $x$ and $y$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z$ and $\theta$ is the argument of $a$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy While $|a|, \theta$ are fixed, $x,y$ vary. Then how could it be constant? Except the case Arthur mentioned, it is not  possible?

Comment: @Grizma If $x$ and $y$ vary, then the only way it can stay constant is if $\log a=\theta=0$, yes. The actual point of the exercise is to show that in _any other case_, the function is indeed unbounded, or more specifically that bounded but non-constant is impossible.

Comment: @Arthur Thx :D I got it now!